# Will importing a database mysqldump that excludes a table from source preserve the table in destination?

Tags: mysql

Moving a database (`db1`) from one server to the next and there was one table (`big_table`) that was so large it took longer to import into the destination than our preferred maintenance window so we kept the application communicating with the source database server while the destination continued to import.

Now we want to redo the process to get what has changed in two steps:

1. dump all tables from source except the `big_table` and make sure we don't overwrite or drop the very large table already in the destination when we import
2. dump the new/updated records from the `big_table` since the last timestamp and import those delta records into the existing destination `db.big_table`

For the first step, will this work to preserve `db1` and `db.big_table` in the destination while recreating all other tables?

```sh
mysqldump -h host1 db1 --ignore-table=db1.big_table --no-create-db | mysql -h host2 db1
```

For the second step, if I know there are no updates and only new records in `big_table` since a known timestamp, will this work do that?

```sh
mysqldump -h host1 db1 big_table --no-create-info --where "timestamp > '${LAST_EXPORTED_TIMESTAMP}'" | mysql -h host2 db1
```

I am trying to understand if each of these "patch" attempts of changes in source since the first import into destination doesn't try to drop/create `db1` or `db1.big_table` but instead just captures and imports all tables except `big_table` and only new records in `big_table` since a known timestamp.

Is there a better way to do this than I've drafted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Bill's proposed different path is a more elegant solution from start to finish leveraging built in replication, I am answering the actual question that was asked which was if an attempt at migrating from source to destination that was started already (using mysqldump and directing output) and try to patch (redo it selectively) it with changes since from the source, could I make sure to not overwrite or drop the large table that was already at the destination.

I took my originally planned attempts of ignoring the `big_table` and doing just rows from `big_table` and wrote to a file and inspected the results just to be sure there were no statements that would results in any creation, dropping or otherwise where and when I didn't want it. I also prepared a backup copy of the `/var/lib/mysql` of the destination just to be sure.

The path I took for this "catch-up" only required stopping the application for a small amount of time even though the original import attempt that included the full `big_table` took quite a long time (hours).

- Update the main `db1` database by redoing full dump (this didn't take much time when omitting `big_table` because everything else was small in comparison) and using `--no-create-db`:

  ```sh
  mysqldump -h host1 db1 --ignore-table=db1.big_table --no-create-db | mysql -h host2 db1
  ```

Since I know there are no updates in `big_table` and only new records (important distinction for how simple this was since no updates were needed) and that ids are incremental I was able to:

- Get the last id in destination:

  ```sh
  mysql -h host2 -ve "SELECT id FROM db1.big_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"
  ```
- Then extract and only load the new records from source into destination (assuming `id` of 4567890 from above) and using `--no-create-info`:

  ```sh
  mysqldump -h host1 db1 big_table --no-create-info --where "id > 4567890" | mysql -h host2 db1
  ```

It worked well and accomplished what I needed for this effort and use case. If were to do this again or with a more complicated table with updates vs only new records or multiple tables that were very large like this, I would probably investigate Bill's proposed path using replication and let mysql do the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 0):

mysqldump does not one table (big_table) that was so large;
you can use meb or xtrabackup

Comment: Not sure why you are saying it can't do it. mysqldump can be used to export a single table `mysqldump db1 big_table > single_table_dump.sql` . It can also be used to export all except a single table. `mysqldump --ignore-table=big_table db1 > all_except_single_table_dump.sql`

Comment: big_table is not table name, i think ,means GB or TB level tables

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is to use MySQL replication.

1. Take a full backup of the source instance. You can use mysqldump, but it's faster to use a physical backup tool like Percona XtraBackup. Make sure you capture the binary log coordinates at the time of the backup (this is enabled by default in XtraBackup).
2. Restore the backup to your new server. Your applications may continue to use the old server while this is going.
3. Configure the new server as a replica of the old one, its source.
4. Start replication and let all changes to all tables replicate to the new server until it is all caught up. This might take minutes to hours, but it doesn't much matter how long it takes, because the applications should still be using the old server while this is syncing up.
5. Take a *very brief* outage to switch applications to use the new server. If your traffic is very busy, you might want to be extra sure that it is fully caught up before letting applications use it for read-write traffic. But it's likely that this will only take a few seconds.

Comment: Interesting approach. Some questions: 1) Can this replication be selective of databases on the master server to replicate vs all? We only need certain databases, not all. 2) There would be a step 6 above for undoing the replication setup on both servers, right? 3) With where we are now even though we used mysqldump to get there, we could just start with step 3, right? Or am I missing something about the need to do the initial restore one way vs another?

Comment: MySQL supports replication filtering by database or by table: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-rules.html

Comment: I would guess you need to start over with a new mysqldump, because by default a dump does not include the binary log coordinates. So you don't know where to start the replication from. I suggest you read here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-howto.html